# How to attach my domain name to my server IP address (Apache)

Tags: apache, dns, hosting

for example I have a domain name www.example1.com

and I have in my apache conf this code:

```
<VirtualHost 109.201.175.107:80>
 DocumentRoot /home/localname/www
 ServerName www.example1.com

 # Other directives here

 </VirtualHost>
```

in the virtual host I wrote my ip and then I attach it to the ServerName is that right?, but anyway when I open the www.example1.com it shows my an error 404, or maybe I need to change the ip address that is attached the domain name, can you tell me step by step what I need to do, I haved searched all the google but didn't understand.

Answer (score 6):

```
<VirtualHost 109.201.175.107:80>
    ServerName   example1.com:80
    ServerAlias  www.example1.com

    //other options 
    ServerAdmin  Email Id

    DocumentRoot /home/localname/www

     # Other directives here
     ErrorLog Physical path to error log folder
</VirtualHost>
```

Please Check this for details
 http://bytes.com/serveradministration/webservers/apache/virtual-hosting/app/dynamic_static_router.html

Comment: What about your domain settings? Do we set our A record and DNS to something?

Answer (score 3):

Your domain name should be mapped with your server public Ip address, this is all required after the configuration that you have made. Ask your dns provider for this.

on ping yourdomainname.com on command prompt, it should resolve your public IP address (109.201.175.107)

Comment: in my admin panel of the domain, i have 2 fields, serverName and ip adress, what should be my serverNAME?, the ip adress i've set

Comment: the serverName should be same as what is your domain name and what you are using in apache configuration file.

Comment: i've set it to the domainName and is equal to the serverName in apache config file, but it doesn't change anything, what i am doing wrong??

Comment: See http://bytes.com/serveradministration/webservers/apache/virtual-hosting/app/dynamic_static_router.html

Answer (score 2):

Solved for Ubuntu 15.04, I found the appropriate solution and hope it will help you too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[Source](https://rohitsalunke.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/domain-name-mapping-in-apache-ubuntu-15-04-without-www-solved/)